# Grepping inside a log with a threshold on the result

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have certain tags stored in a series of .log files and i would like for the grep to show me Only the values > 31, meaning different to 0 and higher than 31

I have this code:

#! /bin/bash

-exec grep -cFH "tag" {} ; | grep -v ':[0-31]$' >> file.txt

echo < file.txt

Output:

I have this result from the grep:

/opt/logs/folder2.log:31

i was expecting not to bring nothing back if the result is 31 or less but still shows the result 31

i have also tried to add:

|tail -n+31

but didn't work

Comment: `[0-31]` means "0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-31]` means "0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 1".

To drop all lines with 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30, and 31, you could use the following:

```
... | grep -ve ':[0-9]$' -e ':[12][0-9]$' -e ':3[01]$'
```

or as single regex:

```
... | grep -v ':\([12]\?[0-9]\|3[01]\)$'
```

With extended grep:

```
... | grep -vE ':([12]?[0-9]|3[01])$'
```

Comment: Thanks very much, didn't know that you could do it like that. It worked!